# GPIO Event not showing in QTreeModel / QWidget / QMainWindow

Tags: python, pyqt, raspberry-pi, pyqt5, gpio

My code below runs on the Pi and the on screen 'Scroll' button works, visibly scrolling the contents of the screen.  I then attach a GPIO button press to the same Scroll method, and whilst the code runs when the hardware button is pressed, the screen does not update until the mouse is moved over the area that should be updated.

I have tried various ways of getting the screen to update, but none have worked:

```py
    self.IQM.dataChanged.emit(QtCore.QModelIndex(), QtCore.QModelIndex())
    self.IQM.layoutChanged.emit()
    self.update()
```

The minimal example code is below.  Any help gratefully received.

Thanks very much

Kevin

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QWidget, QGridLayout
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTreeView, QApplication, qApp, QPushButton

from PyQt5.QtGui import QStandardItemModel, QStandardItem
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, pyqtSlot

import sys

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO


class StartMarshall(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.data = ['XXX' for _ in range(10)]

        # Build Central Widget
        self.widget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.widget)

        # build buttons
        scrollButton = self.createButton(self.scroll, 'Scroll', 'Scroll action')
        exitButton = self.createButton(qApp.quit, 'Exit', 'Exit action')

        # Setup RPI GPIO Hardware Buttons
        # Use Broadcom GPIO numbers (BCM)
        GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
        pinStartGate = 4
        # Setup pinSG as an Input with a pull up resistor attached (ie pull down for press)
        GPIO.setup(pinSG, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
        # Call self.scroll on button press
        GPIO.add_event_detect(pinSG, GPIO.FALLING, callback=self.scroll, bouncetime=300)

        grid = QGridLayout()
        grid.setSpacing(10)

        # intialize view of data
        self.IQ = IQ = QTreeView()

        # Prepopulate View Models
        self.IQM = self.prepModel(IQ)

        self.fillModel(self.IQM, self.data[2:len(self.data)])

        # include the widgets
        grid.addWidget(IQ, 3, 1, -1, -1)

        grid.addWidget(scrollButton, 5, 0)
        grid.addWidget(exitButton, 7, 0)

        self.widget.setLayout(grid)

        # Show QMainWindow
        self.show()
        #self.showFullScreen()
        #self.showMaximized()

    def createButton(self, on_click, btn_txt='button title', btn_tip='this is a button hint'):
        button = QPushButton(btn_txt, self)
        button.setToolTip(btn_tip)
        button.clicked.connect(on_click)
        return button

    def prepModel(self, widget):
        # initialize a model
        model = QStandardItemModel()

        # remove indentation and headers
        widget.setIndentation(0)
        widget.setHeaderHidden(1)

        # add (data) model to widget
        widget.setModel(model)
        return model

    def fillModel(self, model, data):
        # for refilling model data
        for i, d in enumerate(data):
            model.setItem(i, QStandardItem(d))
        return

    @pyqtSlot()
    def scroll(self, event=None):
        print("Scroll")
        # when scroll button is clicked
        if self.data[1:2] == '':  # if second data is blank then no need to scroll
            return

        # remove the first element from data
        self.data.pop(0)

        # add the padded (blank) element from data
        self.data.append('')

        # show the full queue (-1 doesnt show last racer?)
        self.fillModel(self.IQM, self.data[2:len(self.data)])

        return

# Main
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = StartMarshall()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The callback invoked by add_event_detect is executed on a secondary thread, and in Qt it is forbidden to update the GUI from another thread. So the trick is to update the GUI using `QTimer.singleShot(0, ...)` with `functools.partial`:

```py
from functools import partial

# ...

class StartMarshall(QMainWindow):
    # ...

    @pyqtSlot(QStandardItemModel, list)
    def fillModel(self, model, data):
        # for refilling model data
        for i, d in enumerate(data):
            model.setItem(i, QStandardItem(d))
        return

    def scroll(self, event=None):
        print("Scroll")
        # when scroll button is clicked
        # if second data is blank then no need to scroll
        if self.data[1:2] == "":
            return
        # remove the first element from data
        self.data.pop(0)
        # add the padded (blank) element from data
        self.data.append("")
        # show the full queue (-1 doesnt show last racer?)
        wrapper = partial(self.fillModel, self.IQM, self.data[2:])
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, wrapper)
        return
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much @eyllanesc, I have tested that and it works perfectly.  I also note the fix to my little '-1' issue in the original code :)  Unfortunately as I am low on reputation here at the moment I can not show an up vote on the answer.